# VBA automation error in CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the an automation error while invoking the following object

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

The error is showing

**Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
Automation error
Unspecified error**

Can anyone have any idea why this is occuring

'moved code from comments

```
Sub TableExample()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    strURL = Range("B2").Value

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE '
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Range("B2").Value
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Do While .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set doc = IE.document
        GetAllTables doc
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did some search and found some relevant info.

1) Do you have "Enable Protection Mode on"?

2) Try `Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium` instead.

Comment: hey sam I also found those ideas but all those failed here...

Comment: in which way you declared `IE variable`?

Comment: what if you use early binding?

Comment: @sam092 early binding did not help...

Comment: any help or any idea from anyone...can't figure out the issues.

Comment: I have a very similar issue with an always failing code. I have tried most everything except updating IE to 9 or 10 which might help. The better solution seems to be going via a completely different way using an `obj As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` rather than ie but in my case that does not work due to "no permission to the requested URL" any follow up on this let me know please!

Comment: Hey, as said before I am facing the same problem. I have tried something new that seems to have solved the problem (I have not had a single error in over 2.5 hours of running the code). I am obviously scared this response will jinx it but I hope it does not and that it works for you: Include an 'AutoSave' somewhere in your code (I do it for every 10 iterations and that seems to be good enough). No idea why, but it seems to work though it does slow down the code execution somewhat.

Comment: Whenever you use a `Object` variable it is a good idea to explicitly un-`Set` it; at the end of your code always `Set doc = Nothing` and `Set IE = Nothing`

Answer (score 10):

I just wasted 4 hours on this, and I'm facepalming at how easy the solution was.
Excel creates a new activeX instance every time you run the line:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

How exactly that works is out of my league, but those references stick around even after you restart excel. After a couple dozen pile up, excel runs out of memory to make more

Restart your computer, (probably an easier way, but that worked for me) 
and then stick the line

```
IE.Quit
```

at the end of your code

Comment: You can do this to close all the Internet Explorer instances on the current seesion, Windows-> Execute-> Type cmd, then type  taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe

Answer (score 2):

For others who end up here with the same error...

This can also be caused by referencing the `Document` object property in an `InternetExplorer` object that has been quit and set to nothing. That this is not what is happening in this question but the following code throws the same error.

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "google.com"

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

If ie.Document Is Nothing Then 'Error thrown here
    MsgBox "Can't get here"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the code to make sure all IE browsers are fully closed right before the Set line.

`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

Change it to:

Call IE_Sledgehammer

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


Add the Sledgehammer module as its own macro somewhere else in the workbook:

Sub IE_Sledgehammer()

Dim objWMI As Object, objProcess As Object, objProcesses As Object

    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://.")

    Set objProcesses = objWMI.ExecQuery( _

        "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'iexplore.exe'")

    For Each objProcess In objProcesses

    On Error Resume Next

       Call objProcess.Terminate

    Next

   Set objProcesses = Nothing: Set objWMI = Nothing

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's been a while, but here's what I did to fix this seemingly random error.  I added a GoTo line after killing all IE processes, then checked for an error after setting the IE object.  If there is an error, add a delay and try again.  It takes a few times once the error crops up, but it eventually stops.

```
Dim IE As Object
IEErrorReset: Call Shell("cmd.exe taskkill /F /IM /c iexplore.exe")
On Error Resume Next
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    GoTo IEErrorReset
End If
```