# Use autosave with numeric condition

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am looking for a way to use autosave in VBA if an evolving numeric condition is met. Basically, I am looping through a variable called 'input_row' and I would like to use a condition that tests whether that variable is a multiple of 25 for instance:

```
If input_row = (random integer) * 25 Then
ActiveWorkbook.AutoSave
End If
```

Given that my code is constantly crashing due to issues with IE8, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061833/vba-automation-error-in-createobjectinternetexplorer-application), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818004/error-with-vba-scraping-ie-google-patents-computer-restart-temporary-sol) making sure to autosave now and then seems pretty important. At the moment I am saving after every iteration in my loop which works fine but slows down the entire process quite a bit.

Any simple 'if' statement suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Mod` function to test if your number is a multiple of 25:

```
If input_row Mod 25 = 0 Then
    'input_row is a multiple of 25
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured there was a simple function that would do this!

Comment: You get an "Answer" and 2 "Upvotes" for that!? You must be in cahoots with people.  :)