# runtime error '-2147417848 (80010108)'

Tags: excel, vba

i get the error runtime error '-2147417848 (80010108)'

When i try this at one pc it works, i have made an image of it and it doesn't work.
The problem is that he is opening ie and then the code will not work anymore.
At the pc that does work, he doesnt open ie and we can go on with the workprocess.

```
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate url
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

I have tried to set up the internet explorer options of the security all the same.
Already tried another browser.
Tried a new clean image with and a complete copy of the pc through an image.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: check this out: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061833/vba-automation...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061833/vba-automation-error-in-createobjectinternetexplorer-application)

Comment: The three tiny lines of code looks fine, but that could mean nothing if something above the code is incorrect. Is IE even enabled on the 2nd PC? You can enable/disable Windows features through the control panel. Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue a couple days ago. My suggestion is to enable the `Microsoft Internet Controls` in your references libraries, then change whatever's on your `Set IE =` line to `Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium`. Resolved my issue.

[image]

By doing this you avoid having to mess with your internet security options.

Full line:

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate url
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. 
Unfortunately i get the same error. I had the references correct.
I have used Your code but he still is opening internet explorer when i want to reset my countbox.
Also when i place true to false.

I can give You some more of the code

Comment: i have it. I just needed to set chrome to the default browser and used your settings. Thanks and have a great day