# VBA random automation error in CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation, createobject

So...

I searched through the forum, and really found a lot of threads with awesome suggestions, but none of them works ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061833/vba-automation-error-in-createobjectinternetexplorer-application)

Thing is my code randomly breaks on Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application"). After resuming code it is always continuing without a problem. Error msg is:
**Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' Automation error Unspecified error**

After each iteration I do `ie.quit` and `set ie = nothing` and additionally I checked and clear processes, just in case if internetexplorer would pile up and suffocate my computer in the background.

Something like:

```
If CheckIFRunning("INTERNET EXPLORER.EXE") = True Or CheckIFRunning("IEXPLORE.EXE") = True Then oProc.Terminate
```

And like many suggested I tried `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium` but with no luck.

I added `application.wait` as I thought maybe there is a split second where IE is still not close and I'm already starting a new instance but that didn't help as well.

I can add a code, but it is extremely long and my only problem is on CreateObject.

I would like to at least resume execution even if for some reason really there is a problem with creating object (and yes, I've tried `on error resume next`).

Comment: Could you please inform us which IE version you are using? Is it IE 11? You said, after each iteration you are quitting the IE and setting the object to nothing. Is it necessary for you to quit the IE instance? you could just try to use IE.navigate() to navigate to different URL and keep using the same instance could help you minimize the occurrences of the said issue and it can also improve the performance of the code as you are eliminating the repetitive opening and closing of the IE browser.

Comment: If you could inform us of the purpose of the iteration and creating the new IE object every time then we could try to suggest some optimization in your code that might help you avoid the said issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, for now it looks like it is working. At first I introduced this as after "breaking" so many times when I would run on some page that tries to download file, or with login popup and similar, I cleared memory and created new instances because after a while process would be filled with dozens of IE instances. Later I added error handlers for all "special cases" that would stop code from copy/pasting the page but never returned to having just onetime set IE (I would clear it after every iteration - and it has 200.000+ iterations...)

Comment: Thanks for informing us that your current approach is working for now. I suggest you could post your solution as an answer to this question. Let me know, if you have further questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, Unfortunately. My luck was very short. It still stops. It seems that nothing is wrong with websites (no auto-opening scripts and similar). But it stops always now on ie.navigate with err nr: -2147221164 which make no sense. And I just resume code from same spot and everything is fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will help you .

replace

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

with

```
    ' Ignore the error 
    On Error Resume Next
    '  if IE already open then try to get the object 
    Set ie = GetObject(, "InternetExplorer.Application")
    ' Check is there error after the get object 
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ' if an error happen then try to create new IE  
        Err.Clear
       Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    End If
   ' Turn Error reporting back on  
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: An explanation as to why this would solve the problem is welcome.

Comment: I'm going to try this one. But I've already tried with On error goto ErrHndlr but it would never "skip" it to ErrHndlr:. I'll respond ASAP when I see how it is handling

Comment: Unfortunately, as I exected nothing happens. It still stops on `set ie` part. I tried `On error resume next`, `on error got o ErrHndlr`, but the thing is... It still stops on setting up the Object. And for example I just resume it and everything goes fine with same link, same parameters... And I've checked processes in TaskManager,,,it really isn't suffocate with any IE instance.