# Excel VBA HTML errors on second call

Tags: excel, dom

I've Googled my fingers off and can't seem to find relief. Here's my code that sometimes works but mostly doesn't.  Errors are in the comments.

Sub Junk2()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Dim oIE As Object

Dim ht As HTMLDocument

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True

oIE.navigate ("https://www.google.com/search?q=Google.Com")
'This works fine. oIE is good

Do Until oIE.Busy And oIE.readyState = 4
'ERROR Method failed  occurs here oIE is empty
DoEvents
Loop

Set ht = oIE.document 'ERROR 462 OCCURS HERE

End Sub

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22061833/3654325. On my machine this code won't run as pasted here. How are you binding HTMLDocument. May be a typo, but `oIE.Visible = True` should be on a new line? Finally, oIE.Busy may need to equal something. E.G. `oIE.Busy=False` or whatever it should be.

Comment: I found the problem.  Create InternetExplorer.application was opening Edge.  After I told it not to do that, it ran fine. (Except for Google's anti-bot/script thingy).  You're right about the new line. It pasted funny. It's one a separate line in the code.